# JQuery Mobile version 1.1.1 - Page inside Listview child LI

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am having problems with adding a page to a listview sublist (li)..

I'm doing something like this:

```
<ul data-role="listview">
      <li><a href="#">Click me</a>
            <ul>
               <li data-role="page">
                     <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
              <h1>Page Title</h1>
           </div>

           <div data-role="content">
              <p>Page content goes here.</p> 
           </div>

           <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
               <h4>Page Footer</h4>
           </div>
         </li>
        </ul>
       </li>
         </ul>
```

Is there a better way to do this as I have a few problems with it...

- - The fixed header and footer does'nt work on IOS 6 (iphone 3GS)
- - Padding and Margins need setting to 0.

Is this the best way to do this?

Normally a list will contain a sub list with links but I want to sublist to contain the page detail (information page).

Update: Trying this but the link does not link to the page gererated:

```
$.each(data.id, function(index, value){

output += <li>\
<a href="#mypage">\
<h3 class="h3_title">link title</h3>\
</a>\
</li>\
<div id="mypage" data-role="page">\
<div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">\
<h1>Page Title sub</h1>\
</div>\
<div data-role="content">\
one<br/>\
</div>\
<div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">\
<h4>Page Footer</h4>\
</div>\
</div>';

...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add the page as a separate div outside the ul tag and  make the li a link to it. For example:

```
<div id="your-current-page" data-role="page">
  <ul data-role="listview">
  .
  .
  .
    <li><a href="#your-second-page">Click me</a>
  .
  .
  .
  </ul>
</div>
<div id="your-second-page" data-role="page">
  You can put here whatever you'd like
</div>
```

Comment: That would be perfect if it wasn't because the the data is read dynamically from the database / json ...unless you know of a what to do the same on dynamic data?

Comment: If you have this data to generate the ul why wouldn't you have it to generate different pages? I don't see the difference - It is just a different HTML containing the same data as your ul.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would generate an external page and link to it dynamically as there's also data to be passed. Could you give me a bit for info?

Comment: Instead of generating `<li data-role="page">` generate a `<div>` outside the ul. When you put a link `<a href="some-page-id">` JQM searches for a `<div data-role="page" id="some-page-id">` and puts it as the active page.

Comment: OK, I've tried your suggestions but the link does not go to the page or link at all. Please see new added code on update. thanks